# Powerpoint: Is it possible to record audio on each slide separately and then make it into a video?

Tags: audio, video, microsoft-powerpoint

I recorded audio for each of my slides separately using ->audio ->record audio so that in the future, if we need to make modifications, I don't have to re-do the entire video over again. I thought I could then go into screen recording and then click on each slide audio for it to play to make a video but this did not work. I was not able to hear the audio when I played back the screen recording. Is there another way to do this? I basically want to be able to save a copy of the powerpoint with audio on each slide before I make it into a video and I really don't want to audio record the entire powerpoint all at once because I make a lot of mistakes and its long! Help!

Microsoft Powerpoint for Microsoft 365 version 2008

Comment: What screen recorder are you using? This sounds like a simple matter of changing the microphone it uses to Stereo Mix

Comment: Why use a screen recorder? You can use the Export option in PowerPoint to create a video from your slides. (with the recorded sound) :)

Comment: Short version of Emily's much more detailed answer below ... you need to make sure that your audio is set to play automatically (as an animation) or it won't play during the recorded video.

Answer (score 1):

> > Is it possible to record audio on each slide separately and then make it into a video?

You could record audio on each slide separately, once you've edited the recording to your satisfaction, you can export it as a video.

- In **Normal view**, to make modifications on one specificed slider, please click `Delete the narration on the currently selected slide`, then you could click `Record from Current Slide`.

[image]

- In the **Recording window**, if you need to make modifications,the Clear command in the top margin of the window allows you to: `Clear recordings on the current slide`.

> > I was not able to hear the audio when I played back the screen recording. Is there another way to do this?

If you go back to Normal view, do you find the horn icon in the lower right corner like the screenshots below？

[image]

[image].

If yes, please make sure the microphone at the bottom is turned on when recording. Besides, I also suggest you go to Start menu > Settings > System > Sound, say something to test your microphone.

[image]

If there is no problem with the microphone, please refer to the last part of Recording tips in "[Record a slide show with narration and slide timings](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/record-a-slide-show-with-narration-and-slide-timings-0b9502c6-5f6c-40ae-b1e7-e47d8741161c)".

PowerPoint doesn't record audio or video during transitions between slides, so don't speak while advancing the slide. Also, include a brief buffer of silence at the beginning and the end of each slide to make the transitions smooth and ensure that you don't cut off audible narration while transitioning from one slide to the next.